# aws_ssm_document unable to validate YAML automation file from S3

Tags: amazon-web-services, terraform, yaml, terraform-provider-aws, aws-ssm

Getting a returned error when trying to create a AWS Systems Manager automation document via aws_ssm_document Terraform resource.

`Error: creating SSM document: InvalidDocumentContent: YAML not well-formed. at Line: 1, Column: 1`

Test for sanity to create the YAML automation document manually using the same document and also to import it inline (which is less than ideal due to the size)

Sample below of the Terraform resource and the YAML document.

```
resource "aws_ssm_document" "rhel_updates" {
  name            = "TEST-DW"
  document_format = "YAML"
  content         = "YAML"
  document_type   = "Automation"

  attachments_source {
    key    = "SourceUrl"
    values = ["s3://rhel/templates/101/runbooks/test.yaml"]
    name   = "test.yaml"
  }
}
```

```
schemaVersion: '0.3'
description: |-
    cloud.support@test.co.uk
parameters:
  S3ArtifactStore:
    type: String
    default: rhel01
    description: S3 Artifact Store.
  ApiInfrastructureStackName:
    type: String
    description: API InfrastructureStackName.
    default: rhel-api
mainSteps:
  - name: getApiInfrastructureStackOutputs
    action: 'aws:executeAwsApi'
    outputs:
      - Selector: '$.Stacks[0].Outputs'
        Name: Outputs
        Type: MapList
    inputs:
      Service: cloudformation
      Api: DescribeStacks
      StackName: '{{ApiInfrastructureStackName}}'
```

Comment: Does your yaml file start with a blank line?

Comment: @jordanm No, i've also created the document manually to generate the YAML file within Systems Manager to then export it again into S3 and still produces the same error.